# What is the idiom here when static_cast is used on null pointer?

Tags: c++, null, pointer-arithmetic, static-cast

Static analysis flagged this code as nullPointerArithmetic:

```
static_cast<BYTE*>(NULL) + p_row_fields->offsets.back(), // field offset
```

where NULL is defined as `#define NULL 0`
and offsets resolves through typedef to `std::vector<int>`

The line in question is passed as a BYTE* argument to a method call.

My question is - What could be the purpose of this idiom?

Is there any difference between what's shown and the less eclectic direct cast:

```
static_cast<BYTE*>(p_row_fields->offsets.back())
```

Comment: Without seeing adjacent code, there's no real way to explain what the author intended. IIRC arithmetic on pointers that are not to reachable bounds is either undefined behavior or unspecified, so this kind of null-pointer arithmetic would be invalid anyway. Side note: you can't `static_cast` an `int` to a pointer type -- that would require a `reinterpret_cast`. You can only `static_cast` `nullptr` or the literal `0` to a pointer.

Comment: The original expression (adding an integer to a nullptr) is Undefined Behavior unless the integer is 0.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm ok i misunderstood; so this is not just a false positive, but it is truly undefined - can you provide a more specific reference?

Comment: This might be a user-written implementation of `offsetof`. If so, this question demonstrates why `offsetof` is in the standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Null pointer constant converts to any pointer type, resulting in null pointer value of that pointer type. Thus, `static_cast<BYTE*>(NULL)` yields a null pointer of type `BYTE*`. This conversion works implicitly as well.

Strictly speaking, the behaviour of the pointer arithmetic on null is undefined by the standard because (or assuming that) there is no array at the null address.

As far as what the behaviour might be in practice assuming the compiler allows this, one might expect it to behave same as :

```
reinterpret_cast<Byte*>(
    static_cast<std::intptr_t>(
        p_row_fields->offsets.back()
    )
)
```

While this is not UB, there is still technically no standard guarantee that the resulting address is what was intended.

> Is there any difference between what's shown and the less eclectic direct cast:
>
> ```
> static_cast<BYTE*>(p_row_fields->offsets.back())
> ```

Yes, there is a difference. Of integer expressions, only compile time constant prvalues with value 0 are convertible to pointer types. Values other than 0, and lvalues such as `p_row_fields->offsets.back()` can not be static-casted to pointers.

As such, the quoted cast is ill-formed.

Comment: Ah - I can verify that the compiler does not accept this (`'static_cast': cannot convert from '_Ty' to 'BYTE *'`).   So it appears the original author did not want to use `reinterpret_cast` here (which appears to be the 'correct' idiom)

Comment: @giles Or perhaps the original author did not *know* to use `reinterpret_cast` here and instead hacked around for something that seemed to work. ;)

Comment: @JaMiT That's one theory. Another possibility is that they knew about reinterpret_cast, but read that resulting pointer value is unspecified, and thought that they found a "better" way.